# UIapplication to Html script

Tags: html

I've a script in UIapp and currently it is deprecated. Is there any way to convert the code directly into HTML? I've tried someways but none of them works. I don't have much knowledge on the scripts

Looking for to hear from you soon.

I ned equivalent HTML commands for following scripts:

```
  var handler = app.createServerHandler('myClickHandler');
  handler.addCallbackElement(mypanel);
  mybutton.addClickHandler(handler);
```

Comment: Please can you show us what you have tried already so we can get a better understanding? You can read [How to ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more.

Comment: Seems like most of it can be easily translated to JS. Please post a list of the methods you need translated and take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask